# Do I need to keep the TcpClient/TcpListener after establishing a connection?

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient, tcplistener

I would like to implement a `TcpConnection` class wrapping a `Socket` or `NetworkStream`, and I would like to abstract this connection from whether it is a server or client, since my aplication can run in either mode.

e.g `TcpConnection.TcpConnection(NetworkStream stream)` would be the constructor signature and these would be created using `TcpClient` or `TcpListener` maybe in some sort of factory.

I can't tell from the documentation if I need to keep those `TcpClient` or `TcpListener` objects afterwards in terms of the lifetime of my stream/socket. Obviously I don't want to leave these objects floating around, I either want to retain a reference or dispose them.

The documentation for [NetworkStream says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream?view=netcore-3.1)

> You must close the NetworkStream when you are through sending and
> receiving data. **Closing TcpClient does not release the NetworkStream**.

This suggests the stream (and presumably the same for a socket) is *never* reliant on the client/listener - is that correct?

Comment: You could of course make up a quick Proof-Of-Concept ...

Comment: You should read this https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ .
It talks about HttpClient and the underlying problem with TCP connection. It could maybe help you.

Comment: [TcpClient.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.close?view=netcore-3.1) _"Disposes this TcpClient instance and requests that the underlying TCP connection be closed."_ and [TcpClient.Dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.dispose?view=netcore-3.1): _"Releases the managed and unmanaged resources used by the TcpClient"_ - So your connection will be lost - as I read the docs.

Comment: Here's the line that will dispose your underlying stream: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs#L466

Comment: So can anyone clarify "Closing TcpClient does not release the NetworkStream" given this information? I am mis-understanding what it is actually telling me, I think

Comment: @Mr.Boy To me, it appears to be a problem with the docs. For starters, It's not clear what the definition of "release" in the context of "Closing TcpClient does not release the NetworkStream". Unless I'm misreading the code I linked to above, it seems that the `NetworkStream` *is* disposed when `TcpClient` is disposed/closed. I'd trust the code over the documentation, any day.